# Django FileField auto urlencoding problem

Tags: python, django

```
image_file = models.FileField(storage=s3, max_length=512, blank=True)
```

I have a model with theis image_file field backed by s3 storage. The only problem I have with this field is if the filename contains any url-encode-able characters, it will auto encode the filename. For example, if the filename contains `%40`, when retrieve the value from the model, it becomes `%2540`. I wonder if there is a switch I can turn this feature/bug off.

The data in the db is `%40`, but when it goes through a serializer and view, it becomes `%2540` from the json api.

Answer (score 0):

add this line after image_file in model:

```
image_file.save(filename.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), image_file, save=True)
```

Comment: What if the file is not saved by me, but the value of this field is manually updated in the db?